# I am trying to show nearby places for fixed location

Tags: google-maps

This is the link that i have refereed but when i enter the name like atm or school in search box it gives me error in

PlacesDisplayTask.java on googleMap.clear()
NullPointer exception

http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/

I tried another code

this is

```js
   private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_neighborhood);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
     /*   SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
*/

        // Array of place types
        mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

        // Array of place type names
        mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

        // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
        // to populate the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);

        // Getting reference to the Spinner
        mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

        // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
        mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnFind;

        // Getting reference to Find Button
        btnFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);


        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());


        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting Google Map
            fragment.getMapAsync(this);

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map


            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,this );

            // Setting click event lister for the find button
            btnFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];


                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                    sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
                    sb.append("&radius=5000");
                    sb.append("&types=" + type);
                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                    sb.append("&key=YOUR_API_KEY");


                    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data
                    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

                    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());


                }
            });

        }


        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);


            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }

    /** A class, to download Google Places */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

            // Clears all the existing markers
            mGoogleMap.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker.
                //This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(19.0330488, 73.0296625);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("CBD"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        googleMap.setMinZoomPreference(15.0f);
        googleMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Neighborhood Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.soulsystem_4.myapplication/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Neighborhood Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.soulsystem_4.myapplication/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

What shoul i pass 4th parameter in locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, );

it is always saying cast 4th parameter to location listener and when i cast it still it gives me error cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Location listener to ClientAngent ist new in api. They I ahve changed it.
Refer https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/